# Use gcc preprocessor to define filename for #include

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, c-preprocessor

I would like to specify the name of a C include file at compile time as a C flag.

e.g.

```
#include MY_INCLUDE_FILE
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {...}
```

Would be expaned by the pre-processor to

```
#include "some_incfile.h"
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {...}
```

Doing something like this

```
gcc -DMY_INCLUDE_FILE="some_incfile.h" main.c
```

I have attempted using the stringizing operator # to expand but have only gotten errors such as  `error: expected "FILENAME" or <FILENAME>`

Is this even possible?
-D define is not entirely necessary, the important part is that the include filename can be set from the gcc command line

Comment: The idea is good, the problem is shell expansion of the quote marks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to escape the ":

```
gcc -DMY_INCLUDE_FILE=\"some_incfile.h\" main.c
```

Comment: That easy...should of course have remembered to escape `"`. This works well and is what I asked for so it is the accepted answer. The answer from anonymoose also solves my problem.

Answer (score 3):

Use the -include option.

```
gcc -include "somefile.h" main.c
```

Comment: Not exactly what I asked for but solves it equally well, perhaps even in a more elegant way.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it something like that

```
#  if defined AAA
#define INC "x.h"
#elif defined BBB
#define INC "y.h"
#endif

#include INC
```

and from command line you do `gcc -DAAA`.

and of course, you can pass directly `gcc -DINC="\"FILE.h\""` if the file is really randomly generated from outside, by makefiles, etc.

Important is `INC` to be evaluated to a valid file name by the macro expansion procedure (see the Prosser's algorithm).